# How to analyse complexity of algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I got few examples I am currently stuck on. Would appreciate your advice and how to do this. what are the best and worst case for these examples ?

- example 1

[image: example 1]

- example 2

[image: example 2]

- example 3

[image: example 3]

Comment: If you'd like help with your homework it would be nice if you at least convert images to text so we can copy and paste and add comments.  Laziness...

Comment: I am sorry i am kind of new to stack overflow. Didn't know it would help. will edit right away.

Comment: In example 1 for instance, you could write that program; vary `n` and plot it against `k` that should give you the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not gonna give you the answers.  But here's an example of how I would approach it with comments.

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) //This line is executed N times

    for(int j = i; j < N; j++) // This line is executed (N - i) times, for every N

         doSomeWorkOn(i, j);  //This can add complexity as well, but let's assume we're trying to figure out how many times this is called.
```

So note that each time we run the first loop, the amount of work we do in the second loop decreases.  This complicates thing.  If our inner loop read

```
for(int j = 0; ......)
```

Then the answer is simple, it is simply N * N.  N times, we need to do N amount of work.  In this case what we have is

N + (N-1) + (N-2)....(N-N)  If you then google mathematical series you will find that this simplifies to (N(N+1))/2.

EDIT:

Note it will probably be easier to find the series if you do it in reverse from what I did, meaning

```
0+1+2+...(N) = N + (N-1) + (N-2) ... (0) = (N(N+1))/2
```

The 1st approach is most common.  I have a habbit of doing it in reverse because I have the series table memorized, and seeing it in relation to N is more meaningful to me, but form an beginner perspective, it is likely easier for you to start on the lower end, as this is how most help pages/text books/professors will present it.  It is, however, identical.  Whichever way is easiest for you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like homework for an Algorithms class to me, but to analyze iterative algorithms you'll need to use summation rules. *Introduction to the Design and Analysis of Algorithms* by Anany Levitin is a good book to have.

And to go along with what ChrisCM said -

Taken right from the book: [image: Time Efficiency]

Helpful rules: [image: Iterative Algorithm Analysis]